# Why does redirection in `< /dev/urandom tr | tr` work; how does this parse?

Tags: bash, shell

I use this to make passwords:

```
echo $(LC_CTYPE=C < /dev/urandom tr -cd [:graph:] | tr -d '\n' | head -c32) # pwg ##1st
```

Varying length, graph to alnum, or whatever.

I don't understand the redirection being used. I understand the outer $() format but this

```
echo $(LC_CTYPE=C < /dev/urandom tr -cd [:graph:] ...
```

doesn't make sense.

- The LC_CTYPE is setting the character type. Got that.
- `tr` is converting characters to those in the set :graph:. Got that.
- The echo is there to give a line-break.
- But how can you redirecct urandom in to a env variable setting
  expression. ?
- How, does `tr` know to retrieve urandom from before it. ?

To me it seems it should be:

```
echo $(LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd [:graph:] < /dev/urandom | tr -d '\n' | head -c32) # pwg ##2nd
```

Which also works. I just can't understand why the first variant works?

Comment: It works because that's how the shell syntax/grammar is. It's identical to your second version.

Comment: `tr` doesn't know anything; it just reads from stdin. Redirections are processed entirely by the shell.

Comment: `LC_CTYPE=C < /dev/urandom` that is not the same. That to me looks like a redirect to the env setting expression. I think it might be to do with using stdout? @melpomene in my 4th line, can you explain left-to-right the redirection?

Comment: What do you mean, left to right? There's only one redirection there.

Comment: You can write `< /dev/urandom tr` or `tr < /dev/urandom`, and they're treated the same. The fact that you have an environment variable assignment at the beginning of the command doesn't change anything.

Comment: See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/843139/output-redirection-at-the-beginning-of-line).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if it had been a `< /dev/urandom cat -` then I'd probably have got it as cat is explicitly reading stdin, whilst with tr it reads from stdin as standard (no pun intended) and so it didn't click. That plus the "redirections are saved for later processing" makes this clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some info from the manual:

[3.6 Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)

> Before a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected using a special notation interpreted by the shell... The following redirection operators may **precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command**. ...

[3.7.1 Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion)

> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
> 1. The words that the parser has marked as **variable assignments** (those preceding the command name) and **redirections are saved for later processing**.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded (see Shell Expansions). If any words remain after expansion, the first word is taken to be the name of the command and the remaining words are the arguments.
> 3. Redirections are performed as described above (see Redirections).
> 4. The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 2):

`<` doesn't redirect to the thing before the `<` -- it just redirects to stdin.  So the order doesn't really matter.  Whereever it is in command line `< /dev/urandom` redirects stdin of the command to come from /dev/urandom.  Before the command, after the command, before some arguments, after the arguments, doesn't matter.  It just redirects stdin from the specified file or device.

Comment: This is it. Thanks. The problem is that I've read "bash processes redirects from left to right; and that seemed to be at odds with starting an expression with a redirect (as there's no left part to receive the redirect).

Comment: "processes redirects left to right" means that redirections on the left are processed before redirections on the right are (within the same simple command). It doesn't have anything to do with how redirections interact with things that aren't redirections, only how their ordering matters relative to each other.

Comment: Hmm -- it *does* read that way, as of Issue 7. Now I'm tempted (but don't immediately have the time) to go back and figure out whether/when that changed.